# Pandas: how to read data as np.array

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a .tsv file like this:

| sequences | label |
| --- | --- |
| [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]] | 1 |

I want to import the column `sequences` in pd.DataFrame as `np.float64`.

But it turns out like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('AARS.tsv', sep='\t', dtype = np.float64)

ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

I would be grateful if you can give me any suggestions!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first column does not look like it is a `float64`.

You could leave out the `dtype=...`, and check the type of the data:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('aars.tsv', sep='\t', usecols=['label','sequence'])

for item in df.values:
    for i in range(item.size):
       print(type(item[i]), end=" ")
    print()
```

This will output something like (when I created your input correct, I added a line with column titles):

```
<class 'str'> <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition using some of the pandas [**`StringMethods`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html) and [**`pandas.Series.explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

out= (
        pd.read_csv("AARS.tsv", sep="\t", usecols=["sequences"])
            .assign(temp= lambda x: x["sequences"].str.strip("[]")
                                                  .str.replace("\]\s*,\s*\[", ", ",
                                                               regex=True)
                                                  .str.split(","))
                                                  .explode("temp")
                                                  .astype(float)
                                                  .values
     )
```

##### # Output:

```
print(out)

[[0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]]

print(type(out)

numpy.ndarray
```

If you need to reshape your array to 2D, use [**`numpy.reshape`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) :

```
print(np.reshape(out, (-1, 2)))

[[0. 1.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]
```